# Is there any way to get the parameters and their order of a stored proc with PDO?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

Even with naming the params, using "bindParam" requires that I know the order parameters should be in when calling a stored procedure.

Is there any way to either:

- call a stored procedure and during busilding the statement, not have to know the order of the parameters
- or get the name and order of the parameters needed for the stored proc from the statement or PDO object?

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind parameters by name?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE n = :num AND z = :zone");

$stmt->execute(array( "zone" => $zone, "num" => $num ));
```

By the way, I prefer to pass parameters simply by passing an array to execute().  It's not necessary to use bindParam(), and no benefit to doing so.  There's the parameter type specifiers, but if you read the PDO code, these are ignored, at least in the PDO_MySQL driver.

---

Re your comment:  Okay, now I understand your question.

No, there is no way to query a MySQL stored proc to know what parameters it expects, or how you will use them inside the proc.  You have to know your own code at least that much.

Comment: Because order matters. If the stored procedure is defined as having the input variables `SomeProc( one varchar(2), two varhcar(2))` even if I use bindParams to bind by name (for example `bindParam( "one", ...), if the order they're put in the prepared statement is not the same as the order they appear in the stored proc, they'll be sent as the wrong parameters. In C# (using SqlCommand), you don't need to know the order of the parameters, the SqlCommand objects takes care of that itself.